# Android Studio SVG Image has rectangle box behind it

Tags: java, android, svg

I have an SVG image and I have it set up so when I move my finger over the image it tells me that I've "entered an image". But I noticed that there's an invisible box shape around the image, so when my finger is a bit outside the image I still get the "entered image" message. I want to only have it so if I go in the image it will display the message.

How do you remove that invisible box so the only thing my MotionEvent registers is the exact shape of my svg ?

My code:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

   rect1= new Rect(dragon.getLeft(), dragon.getTop(),
           dragon.getRight(), dragon.getBottom());

       rect2= new Rect(buttonTwo.getLeft(), buttonTwo.getTop(),
               buttonTwo.getRight(), buttonTwo.getBottom());
   }

///////////////////////////////////////////////

if (event.getActionMasked() == (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN | MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)) {
    if (rect1.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
        System.out.println(" Dragon Entered ");
    }
}
if (event.getActionMasked() == (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN | MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)) {
    if (rect2.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
        System.out.println(" in button2!!!!: ");
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please clarify what you are asking? [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: my question is how do you remove that invisible box so the only thing my MotionEvent registers is the exact shape of my svg ?